# How to create input form with multiple options?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a form that allows you enter a password that grants access to a specific URL.

For example, enter "facebook", and it takes you to www.facebook.com
Enter, "yahoo", it sends you to www.yahoo.com
Enter, "google",.... you get it.
If one enters anything but those words, it gives an error.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <script language="javascript">
<!--//
/*This Script allows people to enter by using a form that asks for a
UserID and Password*/
function pasuser(form) {
        if(form.id.value=="google") { location="http://www.google.com" } 
        else if(form.id.value=="facebook") { location="http://www.facebook.com" } 
        else if(form.id.value=="yahoo") { location="http://www.yahoo.com" } 

    else {alert("Invalid Password")}
                        }
//-->
</script>

<form name="login">
<input name="id" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Enter Class" onClick="pasuser(this.form)">
</form>
```

However, this doesn't work! Can someone help me set this up! I'd really like to have more than 3 options.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be just super if you would specify the error you received... I left my psychic mind at home today.

Comment: `onClick` should be `onclick`

Comment: Please reword the question as to avoid the use of *password*. Unless you really mean password in the *credentials* sense. In that case: DON'T.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what doesn't work in this particular example (it works, on clicking submit button, not hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd>). But if you want to have more than 3 sites, you could make it easier:

```
<script>
// ...
sites = {
    "google": "http://www.google.com",
    "facebook": "http://www.facebook.com",
    "yahoo": "http://www.yahoo.com"
};
function pasuser(form) {
    if (sites[form.id.value]) {
        window.location = sites[form.id.value];
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Password")
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use "id" as the name of an HTML element since it may conflict with the `id` property.  For the rest of my answer, look at [MBO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866284/beginner-how-to-create-password-form-with-multiple-ifs-switch-options/1866355#1866355)

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to write something along the lines of this:

```
function redirect( ) {
   var textfield = document.getElementById( 'textfield' );
   var location = '#';
   switch( textfield.value ) {
      case 'facebook':
        location = 'http://facebook.com';
        break;
      case 'google':
        location = 'http://google.com';
        break;
      // add as many as you like
   }
   window.location.href = location;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <input id="textfield" type="text" value=""/>
 <input type="button" value="Enter Class" onclick="redirect()"/>
```

You do not need a form to do this URL redirection.

Good luck.

Comment: Except you do need a form to have input elements and valid HTML right?

Comment: No. You can have input elements outside of a form.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to send your user to a specific location, you might want to use `window.location` instead of just `location`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on Firefox 3.5 and IE 8 and it works when you click the button, not when you hit Enter after typing the string. To make it work from enter key, call `return pasuser(this)` from the onsubmit of the form and `return false;` from end of the pasuser function.

```
<form name="login" onsubmit="return pasuser(this)">
function pasuser(form) 
{
    //other code
    else {alert("Invalid Password")}
    return false;
}
```